# Angular Interceptor of Auth 0 and Azure AD are interfering in each other's authentication process

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, auth0, azure-active-directory

I am developing an app which includes both **Auth 0 and Azure AD** for user authentication for different domains. For eg. Auth0 for gmail.com and outlook.com and Azure AD for other domains. I want to keep them separate. For this I am displaying an option page where user selects a login option (Auth0 or AzureAd).

I am using **Angularjs** framework and **.Net**.

Login process of both Auth0 and Azure AD is working smooth if  implemented exclusively using one login option only i.e. either Auth0 or Azure Ad. But it go gibberish when used together. The problem starts in state routing and accessing email of the logged in user from ClaimsPrincipal(.NET). One (Auth0/AzureAd) seems to overwrite ClaimsPrincipal. For eg. if I used **a@b**.com in Azure AD to login and post logout I try to login again by Auth0 with email **c@d.com**, the **ClaimsPrincipal still returns Email of the Azure AD user** i.e. a@b instead of c@d.

I am sure this is happening because there two interceptors intercepting request, one for each. **ProtectedResourceInterceptor: Azure AD** and
  **jwtInterceptor: Auth0**

I tried to create a service provider which dynamically tries to push or pop interceptor from **$httpProvider** on selection of a login option (Auth0/AzureAD).

```
 app.config(['$provide', '$httpProvider', function ($provide, $httpProvider) {
    $provide.decorator('$interceptorManager', ['$delegate', '$injector', function ($delegate, $injector) {
        $delegate.addInterceptor = function (loginOptionValue) {                            
            if (loginOptionValue) {
                switch (loginOptionValue) {
                    case 'Auth 0':
                        var index = $httpProvider.interceptors.indexOf('ProtectedResourceInterceptor');
                        if (index != -1) $httpProvider.interceptors.splice(index, 1);
                        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');
                        break;
                    case 'Azure Ad':
                        var index = $httpProvider.interceptors.indexOf('jwtInterceptor');
                        if (index != -1) $httpProvider.interceptors.splice(index, 1);
                        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('ProtectedResourceInterceptor');
                        break;
                }
            }
            console.log('Adding Interceptio: '+$httpProvider.interceptors.length);
        }
        $delegate.removeInterceptors = function (loginOptionValue) {
            var index = -1;
           //var index = $httpProvider.interceptors.indexOf('ProtectedResourceInterceptor');
           //if (index != -1) $httpProvider.interceptors.splice(index, 1);

           index = $httpProvider.interceptors.indexOf('jwtInterceptor');
           if (index != -1) $httpProvider.interceptors.splice(index, 1);
        }
        $delegate.printInterceptors = function () {
            for (var i = 0 ; i < $httpProvider.interceptors.length ; i++)
                console.log($httpProvider.interceptors[i]);
        }
        return $delegate;
    }]);
}]);
```

But that **doesn't seems to work** out for me. How am I supposed to achieve **uninterrupted login process** while deploying Auth 0 and Azure AD both?

Comment: Is there anyway we can achieve both?

Comment: OK, now, after reading one article I have access to my Azure Active Directory from Auth 0. And I can successfully login to my app. But I have one question. As of now, Auth 0 charges me for each user I add to its directory. Will Auth 0 charge me for each user I add to Azure Active Directory? I am confused because I am not adding user to the Auth 0, I am just using it for login. The user, on the other end, is being added to the Azure AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **discarded** the idea of **accessing Azure Ad from Auth0**. I rollbacked to my previous steps where I had options to choose between the duo (Auth0 or Azure AD).

For anyone who is looking out for the answer, well, **I tried editing the interceptors**. I don't know if I should edit the interceptors but I did a very little and it worked out for me.

So here it goes. I created an `angular value` and named it `loginOption` with a property `value` at the very onset of the `module creation`. `loginOption` could hold either `Auth 0` or `Azure AD` as the value.

```
app.value('loginOption', {value: null});
```

`loginOption.value` is populated when a user selects a loginOption.

For `Auth 0` I edited the file `auth0-angular.js`. I injected `loginOption` in `this.$get` of `authUtilsProvider` and conditioned `$stateChangeStart`

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (e, to) {
  if (!config.initialized) {
    return;
  }
  //prevent state change only when the state change is in the favor of Auth0 or login option is yet to be selected
  //now, it won't prevent state change when done by Azure AD
  if (to.data && to.data.requiresLogin && (!loginOption.value || loginOption.value === 'Auth 0')) {
    if (!auth.isAuthenticated && !auth.refreshTokenPromise) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $injector.get('$state').go(config.loginState);
    }
  }
});
```

For `Azure AD` I edited the file `adal-angular.js`. I injected `loginOption` in `ProtectedResourceInterceptor` and conditioned a few codes.

```
//to prevent adding token of Azure Ad into header of Auth 0 requests
if (tokenStored && (loginOption.value === loginOptions.AZURE_AD)) {
    authService.info('Token is available for this url ' + config.url);
    // check endpoint mapping if provided
    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + tokenStored;
    return config;
}
```

and

```
if (loginOption.value === loginOptions.AZURE_AD) {
    // delayed request to return after iframe completes
    var delayedRequest = $q.defer();
    authService.acquireToken(resource).then(function (token) {
        authService.verbose('Token is available');
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
        delayedRequest.resolve(config);
    }, function (err) {
        config.data = err;
        delayedRequest.reject(config);
    });

    return delayedRequest.promise;
}
```

Nothing has to be done at the back-end. Be sure to add Token Validators for both `Auth0` and `Azure Ad` in `Startup.cs`

```
//for Azure Ad
UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication 

//for Auth0
UseJwtBearerAuthentication
```

And last but not the least, the Claims. For `Auth0`, email could be retrieved from `ClaimTypes.Email` and for `Azure Ad`, email could be retrieved from `ClaimTypes.Name`.

```
public static Claim GetClaim(string claimType)
{
    return ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(claimType);
}

public static string GetLoggedInUserEmail()
{
    //Email comes up for Auth0
    var claimEmail = GetClaim(ClaimTypes.Email);

    //if claimEmail comes out to be null from ClaimTypes.Email then try it out for ClaimTypes.Name
    if (claimEmail == null)
        //Name comes up for Azure AD
        claimEmail = GetClaim(ClaimTypes.Name);

    var email = (claimEmail == null ? string.Empty : claimEmail.Value); //gets the email of the user
    return email;
}
```

I am not sure whether this is a solution for my problem but this is what worked for me. Please do correct me if I am wrong at any point while answering. Thanks